# Is there an alternative way for lookup in ssis for mariadb?

Tags: join, ssis, mariadb, lookup

Suppose we have two tables with the following values:

| ID | Name | Fname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb |
| 3 | cccc | cccc |
| 4 | dddd | dddd |

| ID | AnotherId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |

I'd like to add the `AnotherId` column to the first table as follows:

| ID | Name | Fname | AnotherId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa | 3 |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb | 5 |
| 3 | cccc | cccc | 4 |
| 4 | dddd | dddd | 2 |

This can be easily done with Lookup for SQL server database, but there is no ODBC connection in Lookup for MariaDB database. I have installed ODBC driver and used it many times in ODBC source and ODBC destination, but I can't use it in lookup. It's my lookup provider:

[image]

And It's my data source installed driver:

[image]

I use merge join and union all to get a table like the one below, which contains 16 records. Furthermore, I tried all inner join and left outer join modes, but the result is the same.

| ID | Name | Fname | AnotherId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa | 3 |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa | 5 |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa | 4 |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa | 2 |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb | 3 |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb | 5 |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb | 4 |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb | 2 |
| 3 | cccc | cccc | 3 |
| 3 | cccc | cccc | 5 |
| 3 | cccc | cccc | 4 |
| 3 | cccc | cccc | 2 |
| 4 | dddd | dddd | 3 |
| 4 | dddd | dddd | 5 |
| 4 | dddd | dddd | 4 |
| 4 | dddd | dddd | 2 |

Is there an alternative way to use lookup in this scenario And achieve to my desire table? Or is there a way for lookup to recognize the installed ODBC driver?

| ID | Name | Fname | AnotherId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | aaaa | 3 |
| 2 | bbbb | bbbb | 5 |
| 3 | cccc | cccc | 4 |
| 4 | dddd | dddd | 2 |

Comment: I beleive MariaDB is an ofshoot of MySQL, so this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978007/unable-to-select-odbc-source-in-ssis-lookup as an aside, please note that lookups are very inefficient. My recommendation is to load all data into a database and perform the join there, especially if one of the tables are small

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I didn't say anything about images, I just referenced what is mosty likely an answer. Did it help?

Comment: Sorry @Nick.Mc. Yes it helped me a lot.

Comment: @GeorgRichter, I didn't upload any images of code or errors. I upload the images of the windows explorers that can't represent in textual form. `Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.`

Comment: It would be enough to mention that you use MariaDB ODBC Driver 3.0.17  (=26 bytes) instead of attaching 86KB  image with the same information.

Comment: @GeorgRichter, I have to show others all the drivers installed in my system and other aspects to complete the question so that they can give the best advice in the shortest possible time (suppose maybe other drivers caused the problem due to incompatibility with the version used). [Politely] Just mentioning the ODBC driver type may not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookup component can either use an OLE DB Connection Manager OR it can use a Cache Connection Manager. A Cached Connection manager is what you use when it's not an OLE DB CM.

In your case, you'd have a precursor/priming Data Flow step. ODBC Source -> Cached Connection Destination (name approximate) Flow the data in there that you need for the lookup and identify your key column(s).

In your "actual" data flow, you'll change from OLE DB to Cached Connection Manager

Data flow

[image]

Fill the cache

[image]

- Cached Connection Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/cache-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN
- old blog post on CCM http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-excel-in-ssis-lookup.html